# Hash SHA256 does not match

Tags: system-installation, iso

I open the rufus and select all the correct options to format the device, but I click the # and the SHA256 does not match with hash in the installation page, what to do? Thanks in advance... and of course I cannot format it, I click start and stops in the step 4/5 and then it says ''ISO error : extraction failure''.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try to re-download elementary OS image. I recommend using the magnet link for downloading via torrent client, this ensures that your install image will not corrupted.

For downloading via magnet link press on magnet icon (circled in red on screenshot below).

[image]